# Chrome opens multiple tabs through background script but writes to console only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to write a background script that creates a new tab if a stored item isn't found but it opens up hundreds of new tabs. While chrome's create tab function opens multiple tabs through the background page, `console.log` are run just once. Why exactly is that?

For example:

```
console.log('This runs once');

if (localStorage.hasItem == false){
    chrome.tabs.create({'url':'this-keeps-on-running.html','selected':true});
}
else{
    chrome.tabs.create({'url':'to-infinity.html','selected':true});
}
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._ aka "Forgot my magic crystal ball at home"

Comment: You still don't show the "if a stored item isn't found" bit.

Comment: That isn't necessary in my opinion. The question asks about the behavior of `console.log('foo')` vs chrome exclusive APIs. I'll try to clear it up.

Comment: Well, there's strictly nothing here that resembles a loop / can cause many tabs to open. And as I understand your problem, you don't want that to loop. Or is it strictly about "why isn't my line printed as many times"? Do you see a number to the left of the line? Chrome may be collating identical messages together.

Comment: @DineshKhadka are you sure it's not just showing it once but with a badge showing a number of times it's been logged?

Comment: See this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#message-stacking Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Apologies, English isn't my native language so I hope you'll bear with me. I use console logs in my background script a lot. They pop into the javascript console just once and don't keep running and I was assuming the same goes for other functions as well. But, when writing the aforementioned code, it created hundred of pages. I just want to know why/how it happens.

Comment: The code you quoted - that fragment - can't create hundreds of pages. The issue is in how you call this code. As mentioned, the result will look as one line in the console because of message stacking, but the code is probably called multiple times. You can try using `console.count()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: Maybe because it is running on every page you create?

Comment: The script is specified as background script in the manifest. https://github.com/dineshkhadka/junkiree/blob/master/js/junkiree.js#L30 Here is the script

Comment: Mystery solved. As I predicted, the problem is elsewhere - please read [MCVE guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your `first-run.html`](https://github.com/dineshkhadka/junkiree/blob/d9cc200b8da5270ce7a7f4bfd1d801a8a0ce88ee/first-run.html#L141) (not listed anywhere in the question) loads the same script, causing it to open another copy (forever, or until the item in question is set in `localStorage`)

You only get one `console.log` in the background script, because the code is, indeed, executed only once in the background script - and once in every copy of `first-run.html` that opens.

Let that be a cautionary tale with regards to reusing scripts between extension parts. If you want a common library between parts, make sure it does not execute any top level code (or at least double-check compatibility) and just defines functions to be called.

Comment: Thank you @Xan for pointing that out. It was a stupid newbie mistake. But quite interesting :D